# Reinstall Python without having Python

Tags: software-installation, python

I use Ubuntu 16.04.  I broke my `python2.7` installation and stupidly attempted to reinstall it.  As everyone except me knows, this breaks lots of things including `apt` and restoring from backups.

Is there any way to install `python` (or anything else) without having `python2.7` already installed? I have working versions of `python3`, if that helps.

If not, is there anything I can do other than take another backup and rebuild my system from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Go to packages.ubuntu.com and download the `python2.7-minimal` package for your release of Ubuntu.

Step 2: Use `dpkg` to install `python2.7-minimal` Often that's enough to restore apt to functioning.

Example:

```
 sudo dpkg --install /path/to/wherever/I/downloaded/python2.7-minimal_package_name.deb
```

Obviously, that's not an exact command for you to copy-and-paste. You must determine the path and the exact package name.

Step 3: Then you can use apt for the rest:

`sudo apt install python`

Comment: Thank you!  I tried that (before the other answer appeared) and everything seems to be working normally.  I added sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python which might not be necessary for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have removed `python`, apt will not work
In the terminal, type these commands, they will install python and the required dependencies.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python python-chardet python-colorama python-distlib python-django python-django-tables2 python-six python-html5lib python-lxml python-minimal python-pkg-resources python-setuptools python-urllib3 python-requests python-pip python-virtualenv
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-dnspython
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt update -y
```

Comment: `apt-get` relies on some Python scripts too.